# How to check for several exceptions within one exception block?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

I want to catch several exceptions on the same line, but have different outcome depending on which exception is triggered. I'm trying to summarize a set of numbers in a text file and want to check on value and io errors.

```
try:
   filex = open('test.txt', 'r')
   number = filex.readline().rstrip('\n')
   added = 0
   while number != '':
    added += int(number)
    number = filex.readline().rstrip('\n')
   print(added)
   filex.close()

except (IOError,ValueError):
    if IOError:
       print('IOError')
    else:
       print('ValueError')
```

The issue I'm having is that it will always trigger on the first condition of the IF test.

Comment: Why are you trying this? You will need to use a large `if/elif/else` block. I think is better if you use `Except <Error>` instead. `try/except` will run the right code for the right exception, `if/else` will execute always all conditions.

Answer (score 2):

can use two except for this condition like this

```
try 
  .......
except IOError:
    print('IOError')
except ValueError:
    print('ValueError')
```

Comment: Thanks. I already knew that, but I want to have it happen within one except-block though (because i'm stubborn :P)

Comment: can use `isinstance()` method like solution @Aaron Bentley . this solution good for your condition .

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using one clause per exception.  Here is the "I'm stubborn" version:

```
try:
   filex = open('test.txt', 'r')
   number = filex.readline().rstrip('\n')
   added = 0
   while number != '':
    added += int(number)
    number = filex.readline().rstrip('\n')
   print(added)
   filex.close()

except (IOError,ValueError) as e:
    if isinstance(e, IOError):
       print('IOError')
    else:
       print('ValueError')
```

Here's the clause-per-exception version:

```
try:
   filex = open('test.txt', 'r')
   number = filex.readline().rstrip('\n')
   added = 0
   while number != '':
    added += int(number)
    number = filex.readline().rstrip('\n')
   print(added)
   filex.close()

except IOError:
    print('IOError')
except ValueError:
    print('ValueError')
```

You can see that in the first version, you have to implement type checking, which Python's exception handling would otherwise give you for free.  And the second version is slightly shorter, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
if IOError:
```

I think this line checks the trueness of the class IOError. It ignores the type of error that was raised.

You could maybe do something like  :

```
except (IOError, ValueError) as e:
    if instanceof(e, IOError):
        #...
```